# How to plot boxplots on specific x-values in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to add boxplots for  the reflectance of different spectral bands to an existing plot. Every band has a associated wavelength (blue band = 450, green band = 560, red band = 650)
Let´s say my bands are

```
blue <- rnorm(100, mean = 50)
green <- rnorm(50, mean = 30)
red <- rnorm(150, mean = 75)
wavelength <- c(350:900)
```

with wavelength as a vector for the x-axis

How can i add them to their specific x- position? I only find examples where the x-values are non metric.
My existing plot looks like this:
[existing plot where boxplots need to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nunh8.png)

I´m still new to R. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Timo, I don't understand your question. What kind of plot you want to get? How are colours related to the wavelength? How come the "band" is one number? Shouldn't it be a range? PS: to create plots, try to use `ggplot2`

Comment: Hi Edo, I want to create 3 vertical Boxplots to my already existing plot in the picture.
The boxplot for the vector "blue" for example should be plotted on the x = 450nm. The number 450 represents the whole "blue spectrum" from 420nm to 490nm.
I´m currently trying to understand ggplot2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is what you're looking for.
Or at least a good starting point.

```
# reproducible example
set.seed(1)
blue_band  <- 450
green_band <- 560
red_band   <- 650
blue  <- rnorm(100, mean = 50)
green <- rnorm( 50, mean = 30)
red   <- rnorm(150, mean = 75)
wavelength <- c(350:900)
wavelength_value <- sort(runif(length(wavelength), 50,100))

# your plot with ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
 geom_line(data = NULL, aes(x = wavelength, y = wavelength_value)) +
 geom_boxplot(data = NULL, aes(x = blue_band , y = blue ), colour = "blue" , width = 10) +
 geom_boxplot(data = NULL, aes(x = green_band, y = green), colour = "green", width = 10) +
 geom_boxplot(data = NULL, aes(x = red_band  , y = red  ), colour = "red"  , width = 10)
```

[image]